# Bootstrap 4 + Isotope

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap4, masonry

Использую isotope для создания masonry сетки + Bootstrap 4 (flex):

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){

    function gridMasonry(){
        var grid = $(".grid")
        if( grid.length ){
            
          grid.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            percentPosition: true,
            layoutMode: 'masonry',
            masonry: {
              //columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
            }
          });
            
        }
    }
    gridMasonry();
});
```

```css
.grid-item img {
  height: 192px;
  width: 100%;
  
  object-fit:cover;
}

.y-2.grid-item img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-item {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.6/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row grid">
      <div class="col-sm-3 grid-item y-2">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x900/000/fff&text=1" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 grid-item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=2" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 grid-item y-2">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=3" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 grid-item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=4" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 grid-item y-2">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=5" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 grid-item y-2">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=6" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 grid-item y-2">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=7" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      </div>

      <!-- <div class="grid-sizer col-4"></div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Пробую и `grid-sizer` но блоки все равно "соскакивают". **Крайние колонки с `col-sm-4` идут не по порядку и в одну строку, хотя должны вмещаться.**

**Вопрос:** как совместить bootstrap 4 колонки разной ширины и Isotope masonry сетку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда мы задаём имя класса в параметре [**columnWidth**](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html#columnwidth), блок с этим классом помогает изотопу определить ширину базовой колонки.

Поскольку в вашем примере используются колонки с классами `.col-3`, `.col-4` и `.col-6`, то за ширину базовой колонки нужно взять `.col-1`. (Единица — наибольший общий делитель для 3, 4 и 6.)

Поэтому в последнем HTML-блоке в паре с `.grid-sizer` должен стоять класс `.col-1`, а не `.col-4`.

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){

    function gridMasonry(){
        var grid = $(".grid")
        if( grid.length ){
          grid.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            percentPosition: true,
            layoutMode: 'masonry',
            masonry: {
              columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
            },
          });
        }
    }

    gridMasonry();

});
```

```css
.grid-item img {
  height: 192px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}

.y-2.grid-item img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-item {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.6/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row grid">
    <div class="col-sm-3 grid-item y-2">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x900/000/fff&text=1" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 grid-item">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=2" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 grid-item y-2">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=3" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 grid-item">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=4" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 grid-item y-2">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=5" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 grid-item y-2">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=6" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 grid-item y-2">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=7" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>

    <div class="grid-sizer col-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```